# HTML Start new row every 2 articles

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML / CSS code for some cards, thing is, I need them to start a new row every two 'article' regions.
How can achieve this?

```css
.tiles_bodyLOB {
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tilesLOB {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 1rem;
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}

.tile-styleLOB {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  &:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
  &:focus-within {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--c-gray-800), 0 0 0 4px var(--c-olive-500);
  }
  min-width: 600px;
}

.a-tag:link {
  color: white;
}

.a-tag:hover {
  color: white;
}

.a-tag:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="tile-container">
  <div class="tiles_bodyLOB">
    <article class="tile-styleLOB">
      <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 38px;">
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Text ABC</span>
      </h1>
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 24px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Sub Text 1
                 </span>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="color: white; font-size: 18px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr">
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Case A: 1 
                       00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="tile-styleLOB">
      <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 38px;">
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Text ABC</span>
      </h1>
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 24px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Sub Text 1
                 </span>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="color: white; font-size: 18px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr">
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Case A: 1 
                       00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
      </a>
    </article>


    <article class="tile-styleLOB">
      <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 38px;">
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Text ABC</span>
      </h1>
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 24px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    Sub Text 1
                 </span>
      <a href="#">
        <div style="color: white; font-size: 18px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr">
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Case A: 1 
                       00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
      </a>
    </article>
```

This results into a single row of 'articles' or cards.
How can I start a new row every two cards? (the number of articles will increase in the short term)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap the articles based on screen width then add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.tiles_bodyLOB` in the `CSS`, like this

```css
.tiles_bodyLOB {
    display: flex;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    column-gap: 1rem;
    row-gap: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 8px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

.tilesLOB {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    gap: 1rem;
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
        }
}

.tile-styleLOB {
 background-color: red;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  &:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
  &:focus-within {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--c-gray-800), 0 0 0 4px var(--c-olive-500);
    }
  min-width: 600px;
}

.a-tag:link {color: white;}
.a-tag:hover {color: white;}
.a-tag:visited {color: white;}
```

```html
<div id="tile-container">    
   <div class="tiles_bodyLOB">
        <article class="tile-styleLOB">
           <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 38px;">
             <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Text ABC</span>
           </h1>
             <span style="color: white; font-size: 24px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Sub Text 1
             </span>
           <a href="#">  
               <div style="color: white; font-size: 18px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr">
                   <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Case A: 1 
                   00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               </div>
           </a>
        </article>

        <article class="tile-styleLOB">
           <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 38px;">
             <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Text ABC</span>
           </h1>
             <span style="color: white; font-size: 24px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Sub Text 1
             </span>
           <a href="#">  
               <div style="color: white; font-size: 18px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr">
                   <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Case A: 1 
                   00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               </div>
           </a>
        </article>

        <article class="tile-styleLOB">
           <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 38px;">
             <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Text ABC</span>
           </h1>
             <span style="color: white; font-size: 24px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Sub Text 1
             </span>
           <a href="#">  
               <div style="color: white; font-size: 18px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr">
                   <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Case A: 1 
                   00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               </div>
           </a>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Click `full page` in the snippet to see the warping on large screens.